# Building project stored on another computer

Tags: windows, macos, unity-game-engine, build, local-network

I've developed an app for iOS and Android. My main computer runs Windows 10 and I've created my project entirely on it. To build to iOS you need to use a Mac, so I bought a cheap one second hand. I installed Unity and Xcode on the Mac. I at first tried copying the project across to the Mac, but this took a long time. Instead, I mounted my main PC as a network location and opened the project remotely from on the Mac. Building for iOS (or rather exporting the Xcode project) gets about halfway done, before it crashes. Looking through the log I find the following error:

UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Volumes/C/Users/Peter/Documents/Unity/DD Party Status/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Unity.Analytics.StandardEvents.dll" is denied.

Opening this networked location in Finder shows me that Unity.Analytics.StandardEvents.dll, Unity.Analytics.Tracker.dll and UnityEngine.Purchasing.dll are all locked. For some reason Unity is unable to access these files to finish the build. Copying the files to my NAS and trying to build nets the same result. Can someone please help? I'd hate to have to copy the project in its entirety to the Mac every time I need a new build.

Comment: Opening Unity with a sudo command in the terminal gets me a little further. It gives the message "Creating directory. Creating directory Library/ScriptAssemblies failed. Please ensure there is enough disk space and you have permissions setup correctly." There's 60GB of free space, I don't understand permissions well enough to know what to do here.

Comment: When you copy did you copy only the bits you needed to copy aka assets, projectsettings and packages folders and the files from the top level?  If the DLLs are locked, unlock them, if its anything like windows it is saying I dont know where they came from, they are untrusted so I will make you safe by not letting you use them.

Comment: The frustrating thing is that the build will crash when it can't use these files. Starting a new build they are removed and created again, so you only have a very small window to unlock them and I could not make it work. I did run the Unity editor as root, by using sudo in the terminal. This made a little progress. It gives the message "Creating directory. Creating directory Library/ScriptAssemblies failed. Please ensure there is enough disk space and you have permissions setup correctly." There's 60GB of free space, I don't understand permissions well enough to know what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little further, but I think this solves the main problem described here:
For me it was the purchasing.dll which always was locked. I noticed that the DLL was already locked in the library cache:
⁨
Library⁩/PackageCache⁩/com.unity.purchasing@2.0.6⁩/purchasing.dll

unlocking it here let me build further, although now I have a different gradle build error.